# Проблема с подгрузкой библиотеки

Tags: java, mysql

Простенькое веб-приложение с использванием mysql и tomcat. Вот класс, где производится соиденение.

```
public class DBManager {
    private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?useSSL";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String password = "root";

    public Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new FabricMySQLDriver());
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее скрин ошибки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все дело в том, что в есть зависимость в мавен mysql connector 5.1.38
Но, как я пнял, оно не видит библиотеку